# Redirect output of xargs to file

Tags: bash, find, xargs

I want to delete the first line of every files of a directory and save the corresponding output by appending a '.tmp' at the end of each of the filename. For example, if there is a file named `input.txt` with following content:

```
line 1
line 2
```

I want to create a file in the same directory with name `input.txt.tmp` which will have the following content

```
line 2
```

I'm trying this command:

```
find . -type f | xargs -I '{}' tail -n +2 '{}' > '{}'.tmp
```

The problem is, instead of writing output to separate files with `.tmp` suffix, it creates just one single file named `{}.tmp`. I understand that this is happening because the output redirection is done after `xargs` is completely finished. But is there any way to tell `xargs` that the output redirection is a part of it's argument?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note you can use `find` together with `-exec`, without need to pipe to `xargs`:

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'f={}; tail -n+2 $f > $f.tmp' \;
                            ^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                              |   perform the tail and redirection
                  store the name of the file
```

Comment: Running 'sh -c' from `find` is dangerous if file names are made by evil people.  Try: `touch 'foo; echo Naughty naughty - I could have removed a file'` before running the above.

Comment: This is a fine replacement for the xargs command, but it isn't actually an answer to the question.

Comment: The correct answer is you cannot do this with xargs.   There is an ancillary discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38834168/1334781

Answer (score 2):

If you have GNU Parallel you can run:

```
find . -type f | parallel tail -n +2 {} '>' {}.tmp
```

All new computers have multiple cores, but most programs are serial in nature and will therefore not use the multiple cores. However, many tasks are extremely parallelizeable:

- Run the same program on many files
- Run the same program for every line in a file
- Run the same program for every block in a file

GNU Parallel is a general parallelizer and makes is easy to run jobs in parallel on the same machine or on multiple machines you have ssh access to.

If you have 32 different jobs you want to run on 4 CPUs, a straight forward way to parallelize is to run 8 jobs on each CPU:

[image: Simple scheduling]

GNU Parallel instead spawns a new process when one finishes - keeping the CPUs active and thus saving time:

[image: GNU Parallel scheduling]

**Installation**

A personal installation does not require root access. It can be done in 10 seconds by doing this:

```
$ (wget -O - pi.dk/3 || lynx -source pi.dk/3 || curl pi.dk/3/ || \
   fetch -o - http://pi.dk/3 ) > install.sh
$ sha1sum install.sh | grep 883c667e01eed62f975ad28b6d50e22a
12345678 883c667e 01eed62f 975ad28b 6d50e22a
$ md5sum install.sh | grep cc21b4c943fd03e93ae1ae49e28573c0
cc21b4c9 43fd03e9 3ae1ae49 e28573c0
$ sha512sum install.sh | grep da012ec113b49a54e705f86d51e784ebced224fdf
79945d9d 250b42a4 2067bb00 99da012e c113b49a 54e705f8 6d51e784 ebced224
fdff3f52 ca588d64 e75f6033 61bd543f d631f592 2f87ceb2 ab034149 6df84a35
$ bash install.sh
```

For other installation options see http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/tree/README

**Learn more**

See more examples: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html

Watch the intro videos: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Walk through the tutorial: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html

Sign up for the email list to get support: https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/parallel

Comment: Don't forget to run `parallel --bibtex` once and type `will cite` at the prompt to silence the citation notice without having to run the command as `parallel --citation` every time. #sigh